# How can I return my array of cards?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I creating a card game and I don't know how to return my array, as I have used different methods in the past using instanceof but never just a whole array like this one. I have put my code below:

Card class -

```java
/**
 *
 * Constructor for a single card
 *
 */

public class Card {
  public String number;
  public String suit;

  public Card(String n, String s) {
    number = n;
    suit = s;
  }

  @
  Override
  public String toString() {
    return number + suit;
  }
}
```

Deck class -

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck {
  private ArrayList < Card > cards;

  public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList < Card > ();
  }

  public void buildDeck() throws IOException {

    List < String > cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cards.txt"));



    for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) { //if lines read are smaller than file then read for another card
      cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1))); //add new card to cards array
    }

  }

  public List < Card > getDeck() {
    return cards;

    /*public void shuffle() {
        // fill in
    }*/

  }
}
```

GUI class -

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Game {

  private Scanner scan;
  private Deck deck;

  private void runMenu() {
    String response;
    do {
      printMenu();
      System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
      scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      response = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      switch (response) {
        case "1":
          PrintDeck();
          break;
        case "2":
          ShuffleCards();
          break;
        case "3":
          DealCard();
          break;
        case "4":
          MoveToPrevious();
          break;
        case "5":
          Move2PilesBack();
          break;
        case "6":
          AmalgamateInMiddle();
          break;
        case "7":
          PlayforMe();
          break;
        case "8":
          ShowLowScores();
        case "Q":
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Try again");
      }
    } while (!(response.equals("Q")));
  }

  private void ShowLowScores() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void PlayforMe() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void AmalgamateInMiddle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void Move2PilesBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void MoveToPrevious() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void DealCard() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void ShuffleCards() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  private void PrintDeck() {
    List < Card > buildadeck = deck.getDeck();
    System.out.println(buildadeck);


  }

  private void printMenu() {

    System.out.println("1 -  Print the pack ");
    System.out.println("2 -  Shuffle");
    System.out.println("3 -  Deal a card");
    System.out.println("4 -  Move last pile onto previous one");
    System.out.println("5 -  Move last pile back over two piles");
    System.out.println("6 -  Amalgamate piles in the middle");
    System.out.println("7 -  Play for me");
    System.out.println("8 -  Show low scores");
    System.out.println("q - Quit");

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("****Welcome to patience is virtue****");
    Game cardsgame = new Game();
    cardsgame.runMenu();
    System.out.println("****Thanks for playing****");
  }
}
```

I've just updated the code, no syntax errors but when I run the program I get a Exception problem in PrintDeck, any idea why?

Comment: The array of card is part of th Deck instance that you (should) create in your Game instance. Then use *that* Desk instance to call its methods like `deck.buildDeck()`, `deck.printDeck()`, etc. Returning the (empty) list of cards from the `buildDeck()` method is unnecessary.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: its a NullPointerException linking back to the line where I write deck.getDeck();

Comment: Christoffer Passer updated his answer to adress this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand what you are asking.
Basically you want the method below, to return the list of cards so you can print the list in your GUI?

Use the `buildDeck` method to build your deck and add the cards to the cards list as you already do. You don't need to return anything. Instead you can create a getter method, for the deck as shown below.

```
public void buildDeck() throws IOException {

    List<String> cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cards.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) { //if lines read are smaller than file then read for another card
        cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1))); //add new card to cards array
    }
}

public List<Card> getDeck() {
     return cards;
}
```

In `Game` class you should do this:

```
public class Game {
    private Deck deck;

public void runMenu() {
    deck = new Deck();
    deck.buildDeck();
```

Then in printDeck you can use this instance as follows:

```
public void printDeck() {
    for(Card card : deck.getDeck()) {
        // print card.
    }
}
```

A whole different thing is that your methods should start with a lowercase letter. `printDeck` and not `PrintDeck`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm asking, but if add them to the results array, isn't the array I have declared at the top of the Deck class useless?

Comment: Thanks!, so I need something like :  private void PrintDeck(Deck deck) {
  List<Card> buildadeck = Deck.getDeck();
   
  
 }

Comment: As the other answers say, you should have an instance variable `private Deck deck` in the Game class and then use this instance variable in `printDeck` to call `deck.buildDeck()` and `deck.getDeck()`

Comment: @lrrossi No, the getDeck method isn't static so you can't call it like that.

Comment: I've updated the code, but I get a exception error at runtime in the PrintDeck method in the game/GUI calss

Comment: You need to initialize deck. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @ChristofferPasser don't put deck.buildDeck(); in the print method, each time you want to print something your deck will be rebuild :-)

Comment: Of course not, but it needs to in the code somewhere :-) Better now? @TomJonckheere

Comment: @ChristofferPasser :-) Yes, I'm deleting my answer, yours is more complete now!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the  printDeckMethod to this.

```
private void printDeck(Deck deck) {
  // Print the deck
}
```

This way the print deck is not worried about the creation of a deck, just printing it. Some where else in your code you build the deck.